# android tradefed: unable to push files to device using PushFilePreparer

Tags: android

I need to push a wave file to android device for testing. Since i am using android tradefed, i see i can use PushFileInvoker to copy files from host to test device.
In my xml file:

```
<target_preparer class="com.android.tradefed.targetprep.PushFilePreparer">
   <option name="push" value="testSample_1KHz.wav->sdcard/Music/testmusic/" />
</target_preparer>
```

and testSample_1KHz.wav is in build out directory.
As my test code is not built as part of product image, i need to do this step from testcase.
When i run my test, it says

```
03-02 18:12:17 E/TestInvocation: Local source file 'testSample_1KHz.wav' does not exist
com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError: Local source file 'testSample_1KHz.wav' does not exist 
    at com.android.tradefed.targetprep.PushFilePreparer.fail(PushFilePreparer.java:83)
    at com.android.tradefed.targetprep.PushFilePreparer.setUp(PushFilePreparer.java:137)
```

Some help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/tradefederation/+/master/src/com/android/tradefed/targetprep/PushFilePreparer.java), you need to use a absolute path.

```
<option name="push" value="/absolutePath/test.wav->sdcard/Music/test.wav" />
```